How to check what region instance my existing Firebase project is running on?
I was not the one who set up the project, so I don't know which region was picked on creation. From the URL of my Firebase Functions I can see that those are running on us-central1.

Did you check the location in the Firebase Console?

Yes, I have. I could not find it. That is why I have submitted a Stack Overflow question. I am not a cretin.

So you're interested in knowing the location of the Cloud Functions?

I would like to know the location of all the Firebase services used in my project. Please give me a step-by-step guide on how to find it.

Do you want your Firebase project location?
Log in to the Firebase CLI:
firebase login

List all of your Firebase projects:
firebase projects:list

See location:
firebase projects:locations

Or if the project hasn't spun up services with the default project location or you have a multi-location deployment situation, you can see them individually in the Firebase Console. From their documentation here, only these services require you to configure a location:

Analytics (Analytics reporting location)
Cloud Firestore
Cloud Storage
Cloud Functions
Realtime Database

Analytics — In the Firebase console, go to settings Project settings > Integrations > Google Analytics. Click the account number to open your Google Analytics account, and then go to the Admin panel to find your account's location.
Realtime Database — In the Firebase console, view the list of your database instances and their locations in the Realtime Database Data tab.
Cloud Firestore — In the Firebase console, view the list of your database instances and their locations in the Cloud Firestore Data tab.
Cloud Storage — In the Firebase console, view the list of your buckets and their locations in the Cloud Storage Files tab
Scheduled functions — In the Google Cloud console, go to Cloud Scheduler to view the list of topics for each job and function. The location is the last segment in the name of the topic.
Non-scheduled functions — By default, functions run in the us-central1 region. However, if the location has been explicitly set, you can find the location in your function's source code.
Just follow their doc.

The 'firebase projects:locations' is not a valid command. The whole answer is probably AI generated.
